# Script Error on Performance Point Dashboard Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint, grid, ssas, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I did not have problem with Performance Point grids before. I could do various things on grids like change report type, change layout, filters, expand/collapse dimensions etc. But these days, right click always give me error as shown in image below. And I am not able to do anything on the grid.

[image]

My environment are

> 1. SharePoint Server 2013
> 2. My machine: Windows 10
> 3. SSAS 2016

This problem occurs also on my colleague's computer which has Windows 7 installed. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mind had modified the default ***master pages***, it is when  some JavaScript functions got screwed up. I had to revert them back to their initial versions. It worked like a curse broken free.